# Finding other functions with a Distribution Function.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a problem in my textbook and I was wondering how to go about solving it. So the question reads:

Assume $Q$ is probability with the DF $F$.

Let $F$ = $a$ * $G$ + $(1-a)$ * $H$, where:

$F$ is $0$ when $x$<$0$,

$F$ is $1/4$ + $x$/2 when $0$ <= $x$ < $1/2$,

$F$ is 3/4 when $1/2$ <= $x$ < $1$

$F$ is $1$ - $1/8$ * $e$^(1 - $x$) otherwise.

where $a$ is between $0$ and $1$ and $G$ being a discrete distribution function and $H$ an absolutely continuous function. Find $a$, $G$, and $H$.

I don't really know where to start with this question, if anyone could give me a hint as to where to begin I would appreciate it.

Comment: You can use the cases environment to write the DF nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have some typos in the distribution, but this is how you can solve it.

First, note the points where $F$ is discontinuous. These points of discontinuity are the support of $G$ and the size of the jump at $x$ is $a g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is the probability mass function associated with $G$. Noting that summing $a g(x)$ over its support gives $a$ (since $g$ is a PMF). Now that you have $a$, you can write down $g$ (by simply dividing $a g(x)$ by $a$). Then, you can solve for $H$ by the relation $F = a G + (1-a) H$, since you know $a,G$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the points at which F is discontinuous. Would these be when $x$ = $0$, $1/2$, and $1$?

Comment: It is where $F$ jumps. Since CDF's are increasing, they can only have jump discontinuities. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Jump_discontinuity

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Also I have determined that $a$ * $g$ is $1/4$, but what does summing over the support mean?

Comment: The support of $G$ is the $x$ where $F$ has jumps. Adding together the size of the jumps gives $a$. Fix the CDF in the problem statement, since what you've written is clearly not a CDF.

Comment: I'm sorry, the CDF is supposed to be a piecewise function, but I'm not experienced enough to write piecewise functions in LaTeX. I tried to use a pre-programmed code, but to no avail.

Comment: Please go read what you've written -- clearly, its not a CDF since its not tending to $1$ as $x \to \infty$. Theres a jump at $x=0, 1/2$ and probably at $x=1$ assuming you meant $e^{-(x+1)}$. The size of the jump at $x=0$ is $a g(0)$, the size at $x=1/2$ is $a g(1/2)$ and at $x=1$, the size is $a g(1)$. Then, note $a g(0) + a g(1/2) + a g(1) = a (g(0)+ g(1/2) + g(1)) = a (1) = a$. Now, using this, you can calculate $g(0),g(1/2),g(1)$ to get $g$ (and therefore $G$).

Comment: Ah yes I have fixed the problem now.

Comment: How would you go about finding the CDF from a PMF? I know now that g = 1/3, so how would I find G from that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46562/discussion-between-felicio-grande-and-batman).